# NSURLConnection's delegate method, asking for authenticationChallenge is not getting fired?

Tags: ios, certificate, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I use NSURLConnection to call a webservice and there is a client certificate present in my keychain which I set as the credential in `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge`

After I removed this certificate and adding a new one to keychain, the NSURLConnection still maintains the credential that I give already and gives me back with 417 status error code, which was 200, before I remove the old certificate.

Is there a way to make the NSURLConnection ask for credential, forcefully.? or how can close the existing SSL connection or the authentication challenge's credentials.

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLConnection` is fickle beast, and I've been having a similar problem for the past couple of days. But I've found a solution to my problem and a couple of suggestions to what could possibly be the reason for an issue like the one your having.

**TLS**

First of there is a possibility that what is happening to you is the TLS layer caching the credentials. That is due to it being computationally expensive to establish the TLS connection [[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1727/_index.html)].

Possible solutions to this are to change the DNS name you are using, by for example adding a dot (.) to the end of the string since the DNS protocol accepts a string ending in dots as fully qualified DNS name. I've also seen people adding a hashtag (#) to all URL requests and thus tricking the system to never look for a stored credential but just initiate the  `didRecieveAuthenticationChallenge` call instead [[2](http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/11/i-am-currently-building-iphone.html)].

**Cookies**

Another possibility is that the server is setting a cookie that you would need to clear. You can do that by doing the following:

```
-(void)clearCookies:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedCookieStorage];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString urlString];
    NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookiesForURL:tempURL];

    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies){
        //iterate over all cookies and delete them
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

}
```

**NSURLCredentialStorage**

Now it could be that the credentials are still being stored in the `sharedCredentialStorage` and thus should be erased by doing the following:

```
NSURLCredentialStorage *store = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
if(store !=nil){
   for(NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace in [store allCredentials]){
      NSDictionary *map = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] 
                                  credentialsForProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
      if(map!=nil){
         for(NSString *user in map){
             NSURLCredential *cred = [map objectForKey:user];
             [store removeCredential:cred forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I hope that these will help.